# Logstash grok - Apache access log

Tags: parsing, logstash, logstash-grok

I'd like to parsing my apache access log, but I guess that there are something wrong in my grok pattern.

Following logs are what I want to analyze.

```
 "message": "221.251.246.139 - - [14/Sep/2020:04:56:04 +0000] \"POST /services/api/agent/liveview_image_upload HTTP/1.1\" 200 45 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko\" 6019 234 1618 \"-\""
```

And here's what I've been parsing using that message.

```
%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})) %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes})
```

According to my parsing process, It can parse up to \"-\".  I want to parsing rest of my messages.

How can I parsing the rest?  And are the things I've done so far correct?

Comment: You can use the `%{HTTPD_COMMONLOG}` pattern instead. You can see what it translates to [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/eaf9810fc59c58818787c9a20aef1bc1786034f7/patterns/httpd#L5).

Comment: @baudsp How can I break it apart in detail like parsing, not just in a big way like %{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}?

Comment: This `%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{HTTPDUSER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" (?:-|%{NUMBER:response}) (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes})`? (mind, it's just what `%{HTTPD_COMMONLOG}` translate to)

Comment: @baudsp AH, I see.  I'll do it based on what you told me. Thank you for letting me know.